# Why is the operator norm on matrices well-defined?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Why is the operator norm on matrices as deifned by  $\displaystyle \|A\|_{\operatorname{op}} = \sup {\|Av\|}$ for  $\|v\|=1$ in $V$, where $\|v\|$ is a Euclidean norm of a vector $v$ in a vector space $V$.

The hint for the question is to show that  $\displaystyle \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$ 
 is bounded for all $v$ in $R^n$, but I'm not sure how that relates to the norm being well-defined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined here? That the supremum exists as a finite number?

Comment: That seems to make sense. Is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684758/for-a-matrix-a-is-a-leq-lambda1-2-true  the needed proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Euclidean vector norm if $||v||=1$ then $\forall i \;|v_i| \le 1$. 
Then

$$
|(Av)_i| = |a_{i1}v_1 + a_{i2}v_2 + ...a_{in}v_n| \le |a_{i1}| + |a_{i2}| + ... + |a_{in}|.
$$

So, each coordinate of vector $Av$ is bounded, then it's norm is bounded too and supremum exists.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have that $\frac{||Av||}{||v||}$ is bounded for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ you are essentially done since then we can take the least upper bound of $\{\frac{||Av||}{||v||}: v \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$.  Now it is easy to see that $\frac{||Av||}{||v||} = ||A(\frac{v}{||v||})||$ and $\frac{v}{||v||}$ has norm $1$; that is why you define $||A||_{op}$ as the supremum of $||Av||$ where $||v||=1$.